# Can format of Facebook page name affect SEO?

Tags: seo, facebook, social-media

I was asked to set up a company Facebook page some time ago according the following format, with an underscore connecting the 2 parts of the business name:
'Companyname_aus'
The company HQ is in Germany, their business name is 'COMPANYNAME AG', their Facebook name is also 'COMPANYNAME AG', with a space, no underscore.

I just googled 'COMPANYNAME Australia facebook' and noticed that that the majority of results are of the HQ Facebook page, 'COMPANYNAME AG', including the first result.

Considering that the Companyname_aus has been live more than a year and posts more frequently that the HQ one, I feel it should be dominating the SERP.

Question is, if the page was name 'Companyname Australia', would it perform better?

Is using the underscore in a way that changes the business name a mistake (companyname_aus)?

Note: the 'COMPANY AG' page has a lot more followers, and would have also have some followers in Australia

Answer (score 2):

First, Google treats underscores as a word joiners so `Companyname_aus` will be seen as `Companynameaus`. You should use an hypen as a word separator `Companyname-aus` if you want to target `Companyname aus`.

Second point is your location when you make the search on Google. If you are based in Europe, Google will give you results nearer your location as australian company may not be relevant for an european user.

Comment: Thanks. This is for users searching the Australian company in Australia. I noticed that the German company was dominating the results when I searched the Australian Facebook page and I am in Australia